Authentication with Keycloak in httpx and how to store access token to reuse it later?
I have 2 services and KeyCloak. Service A should get access token from KeyCloak to make requests to service B.
For that I've written Auth subclass to authenticate through KeyCloak:
import typing
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from uuid import UUID

from httpx import Auth, Request, Response, AsyncClient
from jose import JWTError, jwt

from main import settings

ACCESS_TOKEN = ""
PUBLIC_KEY = ""


class IntgrPltfrmAuth(Auth):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = AsyncClient(base_url=settings.INTGR_PLTFRM_KEYCLOAK.SERVER_URL, verify=False)
        self.client_id = settings.INTGR_PLTFRM_KEYCLOAK.CLIENT_ID
        self.client_secret = settings.INTGR_PLTFRM_KEYCLOAK.CLIENT_SECRET
        self.realm = settings.INTGR_PLTFRM_KEYCLOAK.REALM

    async def async_auth_flow(self, request: Request) -> typing.AsyncGenerator[Request, Response]:
        access_token = await self._get_access_token()
        request.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {access_token}"
        response = yield request
        if response.status_code == 401:
            access_token = await self._update_token()
            request.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {access_token}"
            yield request

    async def _get_access_token(self):
        public_key = await self.get_public_key()
        if not self.token_is_valid(token=ACCESS_TOKEN, public_key=public_key):
            await self._update_token()
        return ACCESS_TOKEN

    async def _update_token(self) -> None:
        data = {
            "client_id": self.client_id,
            "client_secret": self.client_secret,
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        }
        resp = await self.client.post(
            url="/auth/realms/CSIP/protocol/openid-connect/token",
            headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
            data=data,
        )
        resp.raise_for_status()
        resp = resp.json()
        global ACCESS_TOKEN
        ACCESS_TOKEN = resp["access_token"]
        return ACCESS_TOKEN

    async def _update_public_key(self) -> None:
        resp = await self.client.get(f"realms/{self.realm}")
        resp.raise_for_status()
        resp = resp.json()
        public_key = resp["public_key"]
        global PUBLIC_KEY
        PUBLIC_KEY = f"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n{public_key}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

    async def get_public_key(self) -> str:
        if not PUBLIC_KEY:
            await self._update_public_key()
        return PUBLIC_KEY

    def token_is_valid(self, token: str, public_key: str) -> bool:
        options = {"verify_signature": True, "verify_exp": True}
        try:
            jwt.decode(token=token, key=public_key, options=options)
        except JWTError:
            return False
        return True

As you could notice to reuse access token and public key I store them globally. What is common practice in those cases? Store in Redis or something like this? I don't like very much storing in global.
